# Increase value of a field inside an array of element

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have documents that has the following structure in my collection:

```
{
    "_id": "1234566780",
    "arrayField": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "count": 3
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "count": 5
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to have a method in my CollectionRepository that increments the value of the field count by giving to the method the collection id and the field id of the elements in the arrayField.

I have the feeling that it is not possible to do it with Spring Data autogenerated queries by method names.

So I'm trying to do it with the @Query annotation, but I have no idea on how to do it, since I need to select the collection based on _id, then select the field inside the array based on id, and then increase the count by one. Any hints?

Comment: Do you want to update the document in the collection just to query it?

Comment: to update it. Actually to increment the field count in +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay, here is a solution to your problem.

You can update a specific element of an array using `arrayFilter` update option. The MongoDB update operation would look like:

```
db.collection.update(
    {"_id":"1234566780"},
    {$inc:{"arrayField.$[elem].count":1}},
    {arrayFilters:[{"elem.id":"2"}]}
```

Admiting you are using MongoDB server and MongoDB java Driver version 3.6 or greater you could use:

```
public void updateCollection () {
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoTemplate.getDb().getCollection("collection");
    Bson query = new Document("_id", "1234566780");
    Bson update = Updates.inc("arrayField.$[elem].count",1);
    UpdateOptions updateOptions = new UpdateOptions().arrayFilters(Arrays.asList( Filters.eq("elem.id","2")));
    collection.updateOne(query, update, updateOptions);
}
```

Indeed Spring data method signature is not likely to generate this update. What I suggest you is to extend a `CustomCollectionRepository` interface with your `CollectionRepository`. You could define this update method signature in this interface and implement it in a `CustomCollectionRepositoryImpl` class. Please find the [part of the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior) that mention this solution.

Comment: good comment, I'm doing it, but the collection is not updated, I still get the previous value, any hint?

Comment: Weird. I've tested it with the example you provided before to post. Could you try using MongoShell with the Javascript method above and tell me if your `count` is incremented? Since I'm pretty sure this is okay with the example document you provided, do you use another document to make your try?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm wondering if it isn't anything related to Spring Data, because as you said, the query looks good.

Comment: Actually, it works, I added a custom interface with a custom implementation using MongoOperatios, I tested it launching the spring boot application and it works. Before that I was testing it using Junit and the query got executed, no, error but the value isn't updated (I retrieve again the element and I can see that the field count is not incremented).